# Difference between (guava) Resources.getResource("bddconf.xml") and properties.getClass().getResourceAsStream("bddconf.xml");

Tags: maven, resources, maven-jetty-plugin

In a maven war project, i use jetty-maven-plugin as developpement container.

i filtered some resources files, and in particular let's name it "bddconf.xml".

This file is filtered by maven and put in target/classes directory.

An old home-made bdd fwk search after this file with this snippet :

```
 Properties properties = new Properties();
 InputStream inputstream = properties.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/bddconf.xml");
```

When i run this snippet, in my webapp (in jetty), inputStream is null.

Whereas with this snippet, in the same method :

```
import com.google.common.io.Resources;
String file = Resources.getResource("bddconf.xml").getFile();
File file2 = new File(file);
logger.info("Does bdd file exists : [" + file2.exists() + "] file : [" + file2.toString() + "]");
// Does bdd file exists : [true] file : [..path..\target\classes\bbdconf.xml]
```

It works, so what's the difference between this two methods ?

Answer (score 1):

May be Properties class and guava Resources class have different ClassLoaders (with different privileges), because Class.getResource() and Resources.getResource() do the same job for you. You can look at the sources of guava:

```
  public static URL getResource(String resourceName) {
    URL url = Resources.class.getClassLoader().getResource(resourceName);
    checkArgument(url != null, "resource %s not found.", resourceName);
    return url;
  }
```

Class.getResource:

```
    name = resolveName(name);
    ClassLoader cl = getClassLoader0();
    if (cl==null) {
        // A system class.
        return ClassLoader.getSystemResource(name);
    }
    return cl.getResource(name);
```